# Need suggestions for designing the app

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am new to iphone programming designs. I have hundreds of plists on my server. On the first launch i will be downloading all these plists into my application and storing it here. What are all the best ways to save and retrieve these plists in my application ? What are the iPhone libraries that should be used to get the best and memory efficient iphone application ?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, the cleanest method that comes to mind would be to use CoreData, download the plists as needed (read: lazily) then instead of writing them out to disk, use CoreData to handle the storage. You'll read the data back from managed objects, and there'll be no mucking about with the filesystem on your part, let it take care of that mess for you.

Answer (score 0):

download files in a separate thread but only as needed, not all at startup.